# "Choose from" vs. "choose of"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

Which one of these is correct?

> - I had two options of which I chose the former.
> - I had two options from which I chose the former.

Comment: They're both fine.

Comment: I first thought your Title should have stated "choose from" vs. "choice of".  Now that I have looked at your question, I don't know if either Title accurately fits the question? 40 views make me feel I am incorrect.

Comment: I find it interesting that "from" and "of" are the same word in many languages.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the first is better (especially if you add a comma: "I had two options, of which I chose the former"). This is because, I think, you can rearrange it to be, "I chose the former of two options."

I can't rearrange the second sentence into a structure like this because the "from" doesn't work: *"I chose the former from two options"? It could be made more euphonious if you made it: "I had two options from which to choose. I chose the former."